# Loading XML into a browser with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Does anyone know why the following code does not work in FireFox but does in IE (on the server) and the other way around locally?

```
function load_xml(msg) {   //this function will load xml even used in IE or any other browser
            if ( typeof msg == 'string') {
                data = new ActiveXObject( 'Microsoft.XMLDOM');
                data.async = false;
                data.loadXML( msg);
                } else {
                    data = msg;
                }
                return data;
        }

        function getTitle(letter) {
            $('#wordle').html('');
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "wordle-list.dat",
        dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text/xml" : "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
                    var xml2 = load_xml(xml);
            var i=0;
            $(xml2).find('wordle').each(function(){
                        $(xml2).find('w').each(function(){ //can change to w:lt(50)
                            var tmpHold = $(this).text();
                            if (tmpHold.substring(0, 1) == letter) {
                                $('#wordle').append('<li class="w">'+$(this).text()+'</li>');
                            }
                        });
                    });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Any errors or failure messages that you could post to help us debug this snippet of code?

Comment: I would ditch the load_xml and simply rely on jQuery to return back the correct xml dom tree, when you set the dataType to simply"xml". Try and see if that works

Comment: Afraid, I have no errors to give you - Firefox and IE both say `200 OK` when retrieving the XML

Comment: @Salman Paracha - that stops both Firefox and IE from returning anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOR EVERYONE WONDERING:

It was because I had the file extension as `.dat` and the server was saying it was a binary mime type...

Answer (score 0):

My guess is because you have ActiveX installed in IE on the server and not on firefox and vice versa on your machine.  Though it's difficult to say from just the code.  At what line does the code fail both on the server and on the client machine?

Comment: It doesn't fail, I get a `200 OK` in Firefox and IE when it retrieves the XML document, but it doesn't pull in the data in Firefox(server) or IE(local).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 function load_xml(msg) {   
         if ( typeof msg == 'string') {
            if (window.DOMParser)//Firefox
              {
                parser=new DOMParser();
                data=parser.parseFromString(msg,"text/xml");
            }else{ // Internet Explorer
               data=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
               data.async="false";
               data.loadXML(msg);
           }
         } else {
            data = msg;
         }
            return data;
    }
```

Comment: I'm afriad this doesn't return the data either (in Firefox). IE works online and local now though - shame I can't provide you with a half point :)

Comment: Hmm, understood..It works for me and i am not thinking other way..Good luck with that